# Debian: The repository CDROM does not have a Release file

Tags: debian, apt, source, error-handling, software-updates

I have just finished installing Debian on my laptop; I had to add manually the drivers for my WiFi card after the installation, I simply installed them via `sudo apt ./name.deb`, where `name.deb` is a `.deb` file with the drivers `ath10k` for my card. I got the drivers from the official Debian repositories. Since I couldn't access the internet during the installation process I choose the official `iso` made for installation without internet access.

All fine and good, however when I go to `sudo apt update` I get this error:

[image]

Why do I get this error? Does it have something to do with the drivers for my WiFi card? Is it something I should fix? If so how?

For more context here is my `etc/apt/sources.list`:

[image]

Comment: Is the Debian CDROM inserted?

Comment: It's better to paste the actual text, instead of a picture of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fine, unless you have the CD (I guess by now it's a USB pendrive, but whatever) inserted, in which case there would be an actual problem.

It's just saying that it won't find packages in the CDROM (likely because it isn't inserted?), but normally you'll install them from the online repo, so you should just comment (add leading `#`) the lines referring to the CDROM, so that the only lines active in your sources.list are those referring to the online repo.

So, you should probably comment out line 3 (and if you ever need it, you can insert the CD and uncomment it temporarily).

---

Regarding the firmware, the following link may be of interest to you:
https://cdimage.debian.org/images/unofficial/non-free/images-including-firmware/

That ISO would have allowed you to connect to the internet during the installation, since it would have installed the needed drivers.

---

Even if you used the official free-only ISO, since I see you have `non-free` enabled, you could have installed the atheros drivers easily with `apt-get install firmware-atheros` (after installation I mean), instead of a manual download.